# Embed require calls in gulp/babel to require a single script file bundle

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, polyfills

I'm using gulp with babel to include polyfills for older browsers we need to support, especially IE:

```
{
  "ignore": ["gulpfile.js"],
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "forceAllTransforms": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

This itself works, e.g. backticks were replaced that cause issue in IE. But every polyfill is included from its single file like this:

```
"use strict";

require("core-js/modules/es6.map");
require("core-js/modules/es6.function.name");
require("core-js/modules/es6.string.iterator");
// ...
```

This cannot be resolved in the browser. It seems that this can be done using [browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify#usage), and maybe some kind of module loader (I'm not familar with this), but would result in a lot of http requests. I simply want a single bundled file with all needed polyfills included.

My gulp task:

```
  return (
    gulp
      .src(jsSources)
      .pipe(concat(targetFile))
      .pipe(babel())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(`${outputFolder}/js`))
  );
```

where `jsSources` is an array of my js files. One of them include.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194393/how-transpiling-nodejs-gulp-task-with-gulp-babel-and-ignore-import) but it seems wrong to simply replace the `require`s by the file content. Is there no cleaner way like `concat` gulp plugin for js?